# asynchronous templateProvider in uiRouter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ended up with a little issue. 
In my UI.state provider I wanted to use a function to get a menu based on a users access, and the users access will be determined by an API call.

All fine so far, have a restangular call that gets the information and generates a menu based on the return (using md-button). My problem is, how do I get the templateProvider to accept the input. 
Below is the code for the route when it is not working.

==================== Simple (and broken) example ============================

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/index",
        views: {
            main: {templateUrl: "page/welcome"},
            menu: {
                templateProvider:
                    function ($http, $stateParams, accessFactory) {
                        return accessFactory.getMenu('home', function(menu){
                            console.log("Got back " + menu);
                            return menu;
                        });
                        //return '<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>';

                    }
            }
        }

    })
```

So things I have checked.

1. The response works, the line that comes our of the function renders the button (the test return without call to function is a copy of the "Got back "+menu
2. If I don't call the function and just do a return, I get the button
3. If I change it to be a call to a function that just returns the string, it works.

This is the function that does not work

```
knowledge.factory('accessFactory', ['$http', "Restangular", '$timeout', function($http, Restangular, $timeout) {
    var service = Restangular.service("access");
    var userAccess=null;
    service.getMyAccess = function(callback) {
        service.one('list').one('me').get().then(function(data){
            userAccess = data;
            callback(userAccess)
        })
    }
    service.MyAccess = function(callback){
        if(userAccess === null ){
            service.getMyAccess(function(data){
                callback(userAccess);
            })
        } else {
            callback(userAccess);
        }
    }


   service.getMenu = function(menutype, callback){


        if (menutype === 'login'){
            callback('<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Login" ui-sref="login"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/unlock.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></md-icon> </md-button>');

//            return '<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Login" ui-sref="login"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/unlock.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>';
        } else if(menutype === 'home'){
            callback('<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>');
        }
```

If I change it to just return the same string, it breaks. Any ideas?

==================== Original (just as broken) example ======================

```
state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                views: {
                    main: {templateUrl: "spage/home"},
                    actionmenu: {templateUrl:"spage/home/actionmenu"},
                    menu: {
                        templateProvider:
                            function ($http, $stateParams,  accessFactory) {
                                //return '<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>';
                                return accessFactory.getMenu('internal', function(menu){
                                    console.log("Got back " + menu);
                                    return menu;
                                    //return menu;
                                });

                                //return accessFactory.getMenu('internal');
                            }
                    }
                }
```

For non asyncronous calls, I can just use return accessFactory.getMenu('internal'). I was thinking I could use Element, but that seems dead in the water.

Any suggestions?

============ Should add part of the factory ================

```
   service.getMenu = function(req, callback){


        if (req === 'login'){
            callback('<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Login" ui-sref="login"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/unlock.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></md-icon> </md-button>');

//            return '<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Login" ui-sref="login"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/unlock.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button><md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>';
        } else if(req === 'home'){
            callback('<md-button class="md-raised md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home" ui-sref="index"><md-icon md-svg-src="/images/icons-svg/home9.svg" class="svg-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></md-icon> </md-button>');
        }
```

And according to documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) it should work

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateProvider: function ($timeout, $stateParams) {
    return $timeout(function () {
      return '<h1>' + $stateParams.contactId + '</h1>'
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

Strangely enough, the timeout version works, with the exact same output as the callback gives, am I just missing something REALLY REALLY obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try return a $promise. Check out the example used on the UI-Router wiki:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateProvider: function ($timeout, $stateParams) {
    return $timeout(function () {
      return '<h1>' + $stateParams.contactId + '</h1>'
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

Notice the line that begins with return $timeout(.... Have you tried that accessFactory.getMenu('home') return a $promise or create a new one with $q.defer() as this:

```
...
templateProvider:
      function ($q, $stateParams, accessFactory) {
          var deferred=$q.defer();
          accessFactory.getMenu('home',function(menu){
                 console.log("Got back " + menu);
                 deferred.resolve(menu);
                });
          return deferred.promise;
          }),
...
```

Comment: Double checked, and I have tried return accessFactory, Currently I am not even doing the call to service.one... The function is currently setup to do a straight callback('[HTML

Comment: OK, I lied, I have not tested that, trying to figure out how to promisify a call back easiest. Should be added that the api call only returns the access of the user, not the HTML menu. but working on it:)

Comment: That does seem to work, well, partially. Do you have a good suggestion on how you promisify a callback? I.E. the current flow is templateProvider calls a getMenu function, which calls a getAccess (that calls updateAccess if Access isn't set). So whats the easiest way of translating that? (sorry, OK'ish on java, still struggling with promise)

Comment: I update the answer adding the promise with $q.defer() but I think that will be better use $q.defer() on the service to generate a promsie that will be resolved (or rejected) according to the success of request. Tell me if will be helped.

Comment: I do agree that from a design perspective it should definitely be done that way. But may have to defer that to the next time (no pun intended). Worked a charm though :)

Comment: Oh, and please enjoy the 50 points, DONT SPEND THEM ALL AT ONCE! :)